# Using Regular expression in VB6 to find an exact wildcard pattern and only returning that string and its location

Tags: regex, vb6

```
Dim strData as String
Dim myRegExp As RegExp
Dim myMatches As MatchCollection
Dim myMatch As Match

strData = "812 F.3aBc 1284|"

Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.IgnoreCase = False
myRegExp.Global = True
myRegExp.Pattern = "[0-9]*[ ]*[0-9a-zA-Z. ]*[ ]*[0-9]*"

Set myMatches = myRegExp.Execute(strData)
blnMatchesFound = IIf(myMatches.Count > 0, True, False)
If blnMatchesFound Then
    For Each myMatch In myMatches
        If Len(myMatch) > 0 Then
            strData = Mid(strData, InStr(1, strData, myMatch.Value))
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End If
```

**Scenario #1:**
strData = "812 F.3aBc 1284|"
The above test code return: myMatch.value = "812 F.3aBc 1284|", which is exactly what I want.

**Scenario #2:**
strData = "Test 812 F.3aBc 1284|"
returns "test 812 F.3aBc 1284|", which is not what I want.  How do I get the returning result to be the exact pattern that I've described in myRegExp.Pattern?  I need the returning result to be "812 F.3aBc 1284|"

**Scenario #3:**
strData = "123 812 F.3aBc 1284|"
returns "123 812 F.3aBc 1284|", which is not what I want.  I need the returning results to be "812 F.3aBc 1284|"

Bottom line, in the return myMatch object, there should only be one item found using each of these 3 scenarios.  Currently, I see Count=3 rather than 1.  The return result described above is save to the first item, and the 2nd & 3rd item has no data.

Comment: Try `[0-9]+ +[0-9a-zA-Z.]+ +[0-9]+` - it's because of the space in the third character class, it's allowing that set to match the whole string if it wanted to (apart from the `|`).

Comment: Thank you, it works...  Will this pattern syntax work for VBA as well?  So, can you elaborate on your explanation?  I see you replaced all of my * with + and secondly, you removed the brackets that wrap all the space.  Is there documentation that you can refer me to that I can use for reference on how to put these patterns syntax together.

Comment: You can keep the brackets around the spaces if you want, doesn't matter. I removed the space from the middle character set. The `+` is a quantifier that means one or more of the previous token, whereas `*` means zero or more.

Comment: humor: I have a problem! I'll use regex (now you have 2 problems!) in VB6! (now you have 3 problems!) :)

Comment: It is documented in VBScript help file http://download.microsoft.com/download/winscript56/Install/5.6/W982KMeXP/EN-US/scrdoc56en.exe. It can be used from any COM language incl VBA. And VB6 uses VBA language.

Comment: Sorry, there was a reason I had that space that you removed.  Scenario #4: strData = "Test 812 F.3 aBc 1284|".  I inserted a space in between "F.3" and "aBc". when I run this dataset, it returns "812 F.3".  What can I do to fix this using the current pattern you've suggested, in order for all 4 scenarios to work?

Comment: You need to use brackets and `submatches` Collection, not `matches` Collection  See that helpfile..

Comment: Your question does not say what you are searching for. You are making us guess your hidden rules. Do you want a string starting 812 and ending in pipe? Then search for that with non greedy regex. If searching for a literal string use `instr`.

Comment: Hi, thanks again for your help and comments.  Bottom line is, it doesn’t matter what the input data is, as long as the pattern matches the wildcard and returns a true condition and the data that was found, that’s all that matters.  Here’s what the data can look like:

Comment: All numeric of any number,size or length, follow by a space or spaces, then all alphanumeric including comma, period and dash in any order and size, follow by space or spaces, and finally, follow by all numeric of any number,size and length including comma,period,pipe and dash.  See pattern string above, we got this working for scenario 1-3, but not scenario-4

Comment: The data can be within a sentence or just plainly the pattern by itself